# Is there a way for accessing the variable in main from another function?

Tags: c++11

This problem asks me about a possible number I could replace HUH? with  so that it prints hello world and then terminates without any errors.

I tried to figure out the address of x in the main function and used some hexadecimal subtraction between the local variable x in the doit function and the address of x in the main function, but no avail. Is there a way for me to perhaps access the contents of the x in the main function and change that value to 0?

Doing so would cause the while loop to stop running and print out "Hello World".

Is this a feasible approach?

```
void doit(void) {
  int x[1];
  x[HUH ? ] = 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
  int x = 1;
  while (x > 0) 
  {
    doit();
  }
  printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Consider declaring [*global* variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) outside (and before) `main`. You really should read some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book

Comment: BTW, if this problem is exactly from a book, it involves some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), even if experimentally, you might find some small positive or negative value of `HUH` which apparently "works" (when the compiler is not optimizing). I find cruel to teach you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only valid index inside `x` is `0`. Any other would trigger [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by out-of-bounds access, and `x` is not used otherwise so you won't get any side-effect out of it.

For example, [Clang 7 on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kh1JAt) completely ignores the access and optimizes `doit` to a simple `ret` in all cases.

Unless, of course, you cram the side effect *into* the index expression:

```
x[std::printf("hello world"), std::exit(0), 0] = 0;
```